# Spark: Difference using map() and map{}

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When programing with Spark in Scala, I see two alternatives:

```
rdd.map(x => (x(5), 1))
```

and

```
rdd.map{x => (x(0), Set(x(1)))}
```

What is the difference between using `()` and `{}`?